# Android: FloatingActionButton Click Event not working

Tags: java, android, xml

I have been implementing a `FloatingActionButton` but somehow hasn't been responding at all. There's no error, nothing happens.

Here is respective `Java` and `xml` code:

I have replaced the code in Click event with a `Log Event`

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.e("ABCD","ABCD");
    }
});
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="edu.ahduni.seas.gyapak.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/textlayout"
tools:context="edu.ahduni.seas.gyapak.MainActivity">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What's error. Post logcat error if any

Comment: Show a `Toast` instead - I'm thinking if you are filtering logcat correctly? Might just be that you aren't showing `Log.e` outputs?

Comment: @indramurari There's no error, nothing happens

Comment: I have edited the question, and checked again by replacing the `Log.e` with a `Toast`, still nothing happens. There's no error. Please don't downvote the question if you can't provide a solution. I can still edit the question according to the requirements. I'm experiencing a lot of intimidation on StackOverflow lately.

Comment: Hey @Mr.Robot... I have checked your code. It's working properly. I got the click event of FloatingActionButton. In your case, what exactly FloatingActionButton is performing? Will you please elaborate a little? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I got the code working 2 days ago. It was just the placement issue of the code of fab as the content view is resetted at every point so I had to set onclicklistener for the new resetted layout as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets put the `Toolbar` and `AppbarLayout` below the `fab`, and see what happens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
                <!-- include  your layout here -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- when the screen is loading, in your case optional -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <include layout="@layout/layout_loading"></include>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- when the screen is empty no data, in your case optional -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <include layout="@layout/layout_empty"></include>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- a fab -->
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            app:backgroundTint="#009688"
            style="@style/FabStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <!-- the toolbar layout -->
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:title="@string/app_name"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

First check the fab click without the content, then try it with the content in content linear layout.

I modified your layout to this (removed all the content) and the click is 
working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:backgroundTint="#FF0000"
        app:rippleColor="#FFF" />



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So your grid view must be taking all the click passthroughs, let me check and get back again.

**[Edit]
It is not `GridView` after all. There was one unnecessary line in the code.** 
Voila found your problem, remove this line on your `onPostExecute()` of `ParseActivity`

```
MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

near Line number 286 probably.

this sets the layout again and doesn't register the on click listener, thats why when it was in the layout file (DownloadZip), it was working.

If it is necessary for you then reinit the layout i.e. find the fab  and put another setOnClickListener. you could put those code in a method and call them on the places you need to reinit layout.

Comment: and not also with content ?

Comment: this layout should work, as I am using it right now so do a small mockup with this layout and see if the fab click works, the behaviour is different when there is no content or there is content. So if there is content, did you receive the click event ?

Comment: No it didn't. But when I set `android:clickable="true"` and also set the property `app:rippleColor="FFF"` I could actually see the ripple effect of the fab icon being clicked. But there's no click event. Weird.

Comment: weird indeed. need more information. can you share more ?

Comment: Sure, should I provide you my Bitbucket link for the src files (All including Java, layout and drawables)?

Comment: or should I upload the whole project so you won't have to create the same?

Comment: upload somewhere and give the link.

Comment: No problem at all.

Comment: You have android:onClick="DownloadZip"  in your fab in the xml and also setting click listener in the code, so does your DownloadZip executes ? you can remove one. I am checking the rest of your codes.

Comment: Yes, the `android:onClick="DownloadZip"` executes perfectly. But after removing the android:onClick part, the fab.setOnClickListener doesn't work whose purpose is to should execute the code of DownloadZip, currently handled by android:onClick.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: there is a boo boo in your onPostExecute I guess.

Comment: Thank You, it's actually necessary to set the layout `activity_main` because when it returns from an empty folder layout, it has to again set the `activity_main` layout back.

Comment: then reset onclicklistener, that simple.

Comment: Also, just minutes ago, I solved the issue myself, all I had to do was move the `fab.OnClickListener` in the `onPostExecute`. Thank You for the help.

Comment: sorry for being late :(, could not look at your code last night.

Comment: It's okay. I actually dreamt last night of the solution that actually worked for me haha xD Now it seems like a petty issue to me.

Comment: I'll award the bounty in 5 hours (SO would allow me after that time)

Comment: btw the dream part was hilarious, yes it also happens to me sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code of activity_main with these :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: and put these gradle file in you build.gradle :  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Comment: They are already there with `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1' compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'` should I downgrade it?

Comment: yes. I have the same issue. than i downgrade it and it will work for me @Mr.Robot

Comment: What should be the compileSdkVersion? 23?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
      targetSdkVersion 23
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Comment: Are you talking about the `AppTheme` ?

Comment: It's still not working. I did all the changes that you mentioned to do.

Comment: It's working now, but not the way I intended it to be, the `onClick` Java function code is still not responding. Instead, I implemented it this way: `android:onClick="myFunction"` in the property of FAB.

Comment: Replace code with this ::    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("ABCD","ABCD");
            }
        });

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but that's what I'm actually doing (I've updated the code in the question, there were formatting issues)

Answer (score 0):

The code is right. Are you sure that you are override

`protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)`

instead of

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)`

?

Example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming_call);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabCall);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("mylog" , "it happens...");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: None. I'm Overriding `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Comment: My MainActivity's code is too long, should I post the whole MainActivity code or can you tell me what specific parts should I provide?